# What can I do to fix my glitches? (Skyrim)

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have been playing Skyrim and the more I play the more glitchy my game is getting. I play on xbox 360. Note: I play 100% Vanilla with no DLC's

Examples:

- Horses start climbing trees
- Dragons flying inside buildings that are out of the rendered Skyrim world.
- My follower floats 1 meter off the ground like it keeps repeating the
    falling animation while flying.
- I sometimes spawn next to dragons that just instantly kill me when I spawn.
- I walk around and I see floating swords that are intangible to my character.

The most recent of examples was when I was shooting at a mammoth behind Fort Greymoor. I shot the mammoth once and it decides to just fly off high up in the sky.

This is very frustrating to me because it prevents me from finishing certain quests. I keep doing the dawnbreaker quest (guide meridias light through the temple) at the end of the quest when I take the dawnbreaker you meet her in the clouds and she is supposed to talk to you. On my game she never appears and then after 5 minutes of being in the clouds I fall down to Skyrim and die. I tried fast travelling but it wouldn't let me.

Is there a way to fix these glitches for the xbox 360? Or do I have to rebuy the game?

Thanks

Comment: What is your game patch version?

Comment: I don't know how to fix this, but I can tell you that rebuying the game definitely won't fix it, so don't do that.

Comment: @ヴァイシャリ it was the latest update so that is patch version 1.9.31.0.8

Comment: Is your Xbox connected to Xbox Live?

Comment: Yes my Xbox is always on xbl. I have a gold membership.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unfortunately the Console versions are very closed source and with a DEV console being out of the question there is not much that can be done my friend, perhaps start a new save **(Don't overwrite your current one)**. and see if the glitching persists. that'd me my first troubleshooting step.